# How to download mashup created in fiware and deploy on own server?

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I am all new to fiware and it is a cool platform . With demo videos I created a mashup which I want to deploy on my server(in fiware cloud).  How can I do that ? How can I download the code and deploy . Please help me out. Keep enjoying fiware.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all, you have to create a packaged version of your workspace (you can skip this step if you have done it). This is accomplished by using the "Upload to my resources" option that appears in the workspace menu:

   [image: Create packaged workspace/mashup]
2. Fill all requested information for creating the packaged version of the workspace.

   If everything goes ok, you will see it on the My Resources view.
3. Open the description of the mashup on the My Resources view and click on the Download button:
4. Upload this file to your instance using the upload view:

   [image: Upload resource]

Take into account that the FIWARE Lab's Mashup portal is currently running a release candidate version of WireCloud 0.7.0 whereas the stable version currently is 0.6.5, so your instance can have problems loading those mashups. We're working for releasing the final 0.7.0 version as soon as possible.

Take a look at to the [WireCloud's User and Programmer guide](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Application_Mashup_-_Wirecloud_-_User_and_Programmer_Guide) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I found a documentation here:

WireCloud Installation and Administration Guide

http://conwet.fi.upm.es/docs/display/wirecloud/WireCloud+Installation+and+Administration+Guide